# Cane Creek Drop V cable compatibility

Tags: brakes, compatibility

Are [Cane Creek Drop V](http://www.canecreek.com/products/brakes-levers/brake-levers) levers compatible with road brake cables or MTB brake cables? Specifically, road cables and MTB cables have different nipples that sit in the brake lever, and I need to know which type these work with.

Anyone have experience with these brakes? I've searched for awhile, and have yet to find any reference to cable compatibility whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website has [drawings](http://www.canecreek.com/resources/products/brakes-levers/manuals/Drop_V_Brake_Lever_Instructions.pdf) that show roadbike cable ends.

Comment: Can you link to them? I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: http://www.canecreek.com/manuals/Brake_Instructions/Drop_V_Brake_Lever_Instructions.pdf

Comment: I can confirm now that this is the correct answer.